# Epoch time comparisons in microseconds

Tags: powershell, datetime, datetime-format, epoch

I'm trying to wrap my head around Epoch time in PowerShell. Basically, I have a CSV that has a column with Epoch time in microseconds. I want to grab only records that fall within "yesterday midnight and today midnight UTC (but not including today midnight UTC").

Will something like this work? How do you convert a datetime to microseconds? I've only seen posts about seconds..

```
$yesterdayMidnight = (Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0).AddDays(-1)
$todayMidnight = Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0
Import-Csv "Q:\data.csv" | ForEach-Object {
if (($_."Time-UTC-MicroSec" -le $yesterdayMidnight) -and ($_."Time-UTC-MicroSec" -lt $todayMidnight)) {
  # do stuff with records
}
```

Example file:

```
ID1    ID2 ID3 Time-UTC-MicroSec
2080101 26  501032  1483232054547470
2080101 5   501032  1483231158598830
2080101 30  501012  1483230264931800
2080101 28  501032  1483230721849650
2080101 28  501032  1483231194379190
```

Comment: Has the comparison to take local time midnight or the utc one? For the microseconds simply multiply/divide with/by 10e5.

Comment: Should be Midnight UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the convert function from [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/). First you just have to divide by a million to convert microseconds back to seconds.

```
Function get-epochDate ($epochDate) { [timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([datetime]'1/1/1970').AddSeconds($epochDate))}

$yesterdayMidnight = (get-date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0).AddDays(-1)
$todayMidnight = get-date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0

Import-CSV "Q:\data.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $dt = get-epochDate ([Double]($_."Time-UTC-MicroSec" / 1000000))
    if(($dt -ge $yesterdayMidnight) -and ($dt -lt $todayMidnight)) {
        #Do Stuff With Records
    }
}
```

Comment: Would there be any issues with rounding? (Sorry I'm not great at math.) Like if it was 11:59 99999xxx in microseconds , and I convert that to seconds, would that go up to midnight? I would want that record to stay though.

Comment: @Esuriency Good question! There is no rounding involved here. You only have to divide by 1,000,000 to convert to seconds because there in no addMicroseconds function for DateTime in powershell, just addSeconds, and addMilliseconds. The Number is Cast to a double to ensure accuracy is maintained.

Comment: PowerShell, unlike most things, rounds to the nearest integer by default.

Comment: @DonCruickshank I believe the behavior you're referring to only occurs when the original datatype of the value your dividing by is already an integer, and you are not being specific about your datatypes. In this case, that would never happen.

Answer (score 0):

To get a proper csv file I did a conversion with:

```
$FileIn = "Q:\Test\2017-01\06\SO_41514002.csv"
(gc $FileIn) -replace " +",","|Set-Content .\Test.csv
```

My approach was the other way round to convert dates to seconds

```
$FileIn = ".\Test.csv"
$unixEpochStart = new-object DateTime 1970,1,1,0,0,0,([DateTimeKind]::Utc)
$UTCNow = [DateTime]::UtcNow
$TodMid = new-object DateTime $UTCNow.Year,$UTCNow.Month,$UTCNow.Day,0,0,0,([DateTimeKind]::Utc)
$YesMid = $TodMid.AddDays(-1)
$TodMidSec = [int]($TodMid - $unixEpochStart).TotalSeconds
$YesMidSec = [int]($YesMid - $unixEpochStart).TotalSeconds

Import-CSV $FileIN | ForEach-Object {
    $dt = [int]($_."Time-UTC-MicroSec" / 1000000)
    "$YesMidSec $dt $TodMidSec"
    if(($dt -ge $yesMidsec) -and ($dt -lt $todMidsec)) {
    "in range"
    }
}
```

The output of the script shows the secs were just out of the range:

```
> .\SO_41514002.ps1
1483574400 1483232055 1483660800
1483574400 1483231159 1483660800
1483574400 1483230265 1483660800
1483574400 1483230722 1483660800
1483574400 1483231194 1483660800
```